# issue with server response

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have the following:

```
 NSString *update_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *status = [parser objectWithString:update_string error:nil];
    NSLog(@"staus %@", [status valueForKey:@"status"]);

    if([status valueForKey:@"status"] == @"1")
    {
        NSLog(@"inside condition");
    }
```

The thing is that the first NSLog

```
NSLog(@"staus %@", [status valueForKey:@"status"]);
```

displays `1` but even though the program won't enter inside the if condition.Any idea?

Comment: are you sure the value returned isnt an int or NSNumber instead of an NSString?

Comment: Try `[[status valueForKey:@"status"] isEqual:@"1"]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use isEqualToString instead of ==

Comment: I get this error when trying that:[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2362f60
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Comment: The truth is that server response should be boolean value-true or false.But when I NSlog it it shows 0 or 1, instead of false or true.

Comment: What if you wrap the left side in [ intValue] and use isEqual as suggested above?

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"staus %@", [status valueForKey:@"status"]);

```
if([[status valueForKey:@"status"] boolValue])
{
    NSLog(@"inside condition");
}
```